# Magento2.3.2: Class Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.2

I am working on magento2.3.2.

When I access my admin panel's any components, I am getting the following error

```
Class Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor does not exist
```

Log is as follows:

> {"0":"Class
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor
>   does not exist","1":"#1
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Backend\...')
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]\n#2
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Backend\...')
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]\n#3
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Backend\...',
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Backend\...')
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php:44]\n#5
>   Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\Backend\...')
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:306]\n#6
>   Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#,
>   array('areaFrontName' => 'admin', 'moduleFrontName' => 'admin',
>   'actionPath' => 'dashboard', 'actionName' => 'index', 'variables' =>
>   array('key' => '720c1261e72c04f8...'))) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:167]\n#7
>   Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:95]\n#8
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#9
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#10
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#11
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#),
>   array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...',
>   'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#12
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000025bdc7d1000000003a4419c4#)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#13
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#14
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#15
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000025bdc7af000000003a4419c4#)
>   called at
>   [index.php:39]\n</pre>","url":"/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/720c1261e72c04f8304c8497ebc2bed31baa2d8388ab3087acd79d30fc880fc3/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try run cmd:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I just edited the description

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove generated folder

```
rm -rf generated/
```

hope it works

Comment: I just edited the description

Comment: did you remove generated?

Comment: yes removed folder